# Re-adding a property removed from a generic type with `Omit` results in incompatible type

Tags: typescript, generics, types

Consider the following code:

```
interface Params {
  prop1 : number;
  prop2 : string;
}

function f<T extends Params>(f2 : (t : T) => void, params : Omit<T, "prop1">) {
  f2({ ...params, prop1: 4 }); // error: not assignable to type T
}
```

`f` accepts a type parameter `T` that derives from `Params`. The argument `f2` is a function that accepts one argument of type `T`. The argument `params` is of type `T`, but with `prop1` removed.

I then attempt to call `f2`, passing it an object created from `params`, with the missing property `prop1` re-added. However, this results in an error:

```
Argument of type 'Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "prop1">> & { prop1: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'. ts(2345)
```

Naturally, using `T` as the type of `params` in `f` and passing that directly to `f2` results in no errors.

I suspect the error is caused by the fact that `T`'s version of `prop1` needn't be fully compatible with what `Params` specifies (`T` could for instance declare it `readonly`), and so by just re-adding the property when calling `f2` I haven't necessarily provided a type compatible with `T`.

- Is my analysis correct, or is there another reason?
- The error can be fixed with a simple cast to `T`:

  ```
  f2({ ...params, prop1: 4 } as T);
  ```

  sadly, this does not prevent me from passing an object with `prop1` missing altogether, since this also results in no errors:

  ```
  f2({ ...params } as T); // wrong, but no error
  ```

  Is there a better way to fix this (i.e. not using a potentially unsafe cast)?

My TS version is 3.4.1, and `Omit` is defined as follows:

```
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
```

Comment: At least in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwChlkAHKAe1IEZkAuZEAVywCNoBuYsy0gJnrIcYKKADmXAL6FCMJiARhgFEMhgAeACrIIAD0ggAJnnSZcAPgAUMAQ0thBmgJTIAvOeQA3CsEMAaMgxsPAYAeSxgMC0AgCJyKmoY8xciEhtLfGQAOhzSINwA+JoGABZkSScOZAB6ap0oSigGEAoHOBwcYDEQOFYAGxQwCmQwAE9SFE1CSSA), the error message continues after what you've quoted with more explanation: *"'Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "prop1">> & { prop1: number; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Params'."*

Comment: (If that helps. It doesn't help *me*, I'm still relatively new to TypeScript, but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect the error is caused by the fact that `T`'s version of `prop1` needn't be fully compatible with what `Params` specifies (`T` could for instance declare it `readonly`), and so by just re-adding the property when calling `f2` I haven't necessarily provided a type compatible with `T`.

Yes, here's another example:

```
interface ParanoidParams extends Params {
  prop1: 123;
  prop2: "abc";
  prop3: true;
}

function cb(p: ParanoidParams) {
  console.log({ 123: "yep" }[p.prop1].toUpperCase());
}

f(cb, { prop2: "abc", prop3: true }); // explodes at runtime
```

You can extend an existing object type either by adding new properties or by *narrowing existing properties*; it is this latter possibility that causes the compiler to balk at your function call. The compiler cares that `number` might not be assignable to `T['prop1']`, and it complains.  This is therefore the compiler working as intended, as shown in [microsoft/TypeScript#13442](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442), an issue about a similar problem.

Note that it is possible to write such manipulations with `Pick` and `Omit` which are safe, but that the compiler still fails to verify as safe and outputs the same error (see [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158) for an example).  So sometimes the reason for an error like this is that the language designers didn't implement higher-order type analysis necessary to see what you're doing as safe... either because it's too difficult to implement, or it's straightforward to implement but the performance impact isn't worth the relatively rare times when it would be useful.

In such cases it's often reasonable to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and move on.  Even in your case where it's technically unsafe, you might want to use an assertion:

```
function f<T extends Params>(f2: (t: T) => void, params: Omit<T, "prop1">) {
  f2({ ...params, prop1: 4 } as T); // judicious type assertion
}
```

Yes, that runs the risk that someone will pass in an `f2` that accepts a pathological subtype of `Params` such as `ParanoidParams`, but if in practice this is unlikely then the risk might be acceptable to you.

Otherwise, if you want a safer call signature for `f` that prevents `ParanoidParams` you can do it like this:

```
function fSafer<T extends Omit<Params, "prop1">>(
  f2: (t: T & { prop1: number }) => void,
  params: T
) {
  f2({ ...params, prop1: 4 }); // okay
}

fSafer(cb, { prop2: "abc", prop3: true }); // error at compile time now
```

It's up to you.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgZ2QbwFgAoZZABygHtyBGALmRAFcsAjaAbhLMpoCZGOMFFABzbsQC+JEjGYgEYYFRDIYAHgAqyCAA9IIACZ50mXAD4AFDEHIrYRloCUyALwXkANyrAjAGgoMbBxGAHksYDBtQIAiPjpYi1ciUnV+K3xkADpc8mDcQISGZAAWZClkODwXTmQAenrkACtmI2AEFWY8MABPchRqnGhlVRIZYhJQSFhEFDM4EF8jBdxdAwhjUwK8VN5qOkZafgBmSX2BRli4NgRY84oDk8YRZghJCflFUbUENityIwFks-KscCkeMgEKocFQADYQbJwqhiTLIY7PZCxXoQcixCoAbXI2WKAF1smAqABVcgDKAAYWqECszmcH1kxBgVj+gSyCTs11usSKTxeUDeFTZDSa+nIyKMEDwcDAyHF4GAWAgHK+ShUahgAGU4DBoNp1oYTMgIlENGC4sUktZIbZGA4nMgAGQER40EosdjQSXuTw+Pz+SH5cyhZBaEgQtK2NG5Ek7EW+xjlKRS8bao0mqDcti8n3kAU3O5p8iY14oLN1Rq6KDUKBVFXQrDkYAI5DKTVVOGwkhAA)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, although I'm not sure it covers everything:

```js
function f<T extends Params, P extends Omit<T, "prop1">>(f2 : (t : P & Pick<T, "prop1">) => void, params : P) {
  f2({ ...params, prop1: 4 });
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that seems to work as I originally intended. Any idea why TypeScript thinks that `Omit<T, "prop"> & { prop } !== T`, but `Omit<T, "prop"> & Pick<T, "prop"> === T`?

Comment: Substituting `{ prop1: number }` for `Pick<T, "prop1">` would also still work. Those two are equal. The key change I made was replacing `T` for the parameter of `f2` with `P & Pick<T, "prop1">`.
I don't really know yet why TypeScript doesn't accept your initial implementation. If I find something out I'll update the answer...

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to find a good reason why this happens. It might even be a bug. My best guess is that TypeScript doesn't see `Omit<T, "prop1"> & Pick<T, "prop1">` as `T`. Instead it views it as something with _equal_ structure. And then for some reason having this applied to a generic type instead of a fixed one, causes issues. I would consider opening a Github issue on the TypeScript project about this.

Comment: There is already an open issue about `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` not being mutually assignable with `T` at [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158) (relevant comment linked there); the compiler just doesn't perform such analysis at the moment.